# Error while trying to loop arraylist from a comma separated string as input

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am getting error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1 at Section5.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:51)`

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the shipment details :");
        String userDetail = sc.nextLine();
        String userDetailParts[] = userDetail.split(",");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userDetailParts));
        
        Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
        shipment.setid(userDetailParts[0]); 
        shipment.setsourcePort(userDetailParts[1]); 
        shipment.setdestinationPort(userDetailParts[2]);
        shipment.setexpectedDeliveryDate(sdf.parse(userDetailParts[3])); 
        shipment.setcustomerName(userDetailParts[4]);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of shipment status :");
        int  n = sc.nextInt();
        
       
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
        
        for (int i=1;i <= n;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the shipment status " +i+ " details :");
        String userDetail1 = sc.next();
        String userDetailParts1[] = userDetail1.split(",");
        ShipmentStatus SS= new ShipmentStatus();
        for (int j = 0; j < userDetail1.length(); j++)
        {
            
             SS.setarrivalPort(userDetailParts1[0]); 
             SS.setdeparturePort(userDetailParts1[1]); //error is observed on this line
             SS.setarrivedDate(sdf1.parse(userDetailParts1[2]));
             SS.setdstatus((userDetailParts1[3])); 
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userDetailParts1));
        }
       
        ShipmentBO bo = new ShipmentBO();
       bo.displayStatusOfShipment(shipment);
            
    }   
    }
```

input and error as below:

> Enter the shipment details :
>
> STAJU01,Hong Kong,Cochin,20-05-2017,karthick
>
> Enter the number of shipment status :
>
> 3
>
> Enter the shipment status 1 details :
>
> Hong Kong,Kolkata,17-05-2017,arrived

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
> at Section5.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:51)

Comment: Try using **String userDetail1 = sc.nextLine();** instead of String userDetail1 = sc.next();. next will stop at Hong because of the space that follows it.

Comment: useful: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String userDetail1 = sc.next();
String userDetailParts1[] = userDetail1.split(",");
```

and:

```
Hong Kong,Kolkata,17-05-2017,arrived
```

sc.next() will capture a single string token, hence "Hong".
You wanted sc.nextLine() I think.

Comment: And to face problem after that change see [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: Yes, the unconsumed \n arising from ```int  n = sc.nextInt();```

Comment: and then the loop condition is bad (and the loop is useless)

Comment: Are we trying to fix every problem in his program or just answer his question?

Comment: if i use sc.nextLine() the output is displayed as below.Enter the shipment details :
STAJU01,Hong Kong,Cochin,20-05-2017,karthick
Enter the number of shipment status :
3
Enter the shipment status 1 details :
Enter the shipment status 2 details :

Comment: i am not able enter details for shipment status 1